# Is it possible to Create Foreign key relation with text columns in Sqite?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I want some Fk relation as below code, let i have a table **Employee & EmpMetadata**

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee] (
    [Empid] integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [FName] text NOT NULL,
    [lname] text NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [EmpMetadata] (
    [Name] text NOT NULL,
    [Value] text NOT NULL,
    [lname] text,
    PRIMARY KEY (Name, Value, lname),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Emp] FOREIGN KEY ([lname]) REFERENCES [Employee]
    ([lname]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When I am excecuting it , it excecuted successfully, but when m generating **edmx** for this the relation is not showing. Those two tables are showing as separate entity.

I used `Constraint lname_unique UNIQUE(lname)` in Employee table, though it's excecuted correctly but in **edmx** file its not showing relation.

But if i use

```
 CREATE TABLE [EmpMetadata] (
        [Id] integer NOT NULL,
        [Value] text NOT NULL,
        [lname] text,
        PRIMARY KEY (Id, Value, lname),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_Emp] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Employee]
        ([Empid]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

Then in **edmx** file, the FK relationship is showing correctly.

Can anyone tell me why it's not generating Fk relationship if I use **text** column as foreign key to relate those table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the soultion the table structure should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee] (
    [Empid] integer NOT NULL,
    [FName] text NOT NULL,
    [lname] text NOT NULL,
    Primary Key (Empid, lname)
)

CREATE TABLE [EmpMetadata] (
    [Name] text NOT NULL,
    [Value] text NOT NULL,
    [lname] text,
    PRIMARY KEY (Name, Value, lname),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Emp] FOREIGN KEY ([lname]) REFERENCES [Employee]
    ([lname]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```